# How to add additional component as prop to a reusable component in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, react-props

I have a simple card component which takes a title and description as props. I wanted to reuse the component but this time I only want to add a button the component without changing the original component.

For example, below is the card component.

```
export const SimpleCard = React.memo(function SimpleCard({
  title,
  description,
}) {
  const styles = useStyles();
  const shadowStyles = useOverShadowStyles();
  return (
    <Card className={cx(styles.root, shadowStyles.root)}>
      <CardContent>
        <Typography variant="h5" align="center" style={{ fontWeight: "bold" }}>
          {title}
        </Typography>
        <Typography variant="subtitle1" align="center">
          {description}
        </Typography>
      </CardContent>
    </Card>
  );
});

export default SimpleCard;
```

So now, I want to import the `<SimpleCard/>` component and just pass the a new button component as a prop.
I'm using the card component in other places so I need to have this original component without the button component. I know I can make another separate Card with button component or just pass an empty prop to the Card component with button but I want to know if it's possible to access the original Card component and add the button component as props.

I imagine it would be something like this.

```
<SimpleCard
          title={"Just shoot us an inquiry about your dream app or website!"}
          description={`Send us more details and we can discuss further`}
          How to pass the <Button/> component from here?
        />
```

Comment: Add button to the SImpleCard . you can add a button `title` and `on click`, if those are passed as props show a button otherwise don't. Its one way to go about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `children` prop and put your content as the content of your JSX as in the following example:

```
<SimpleCard>
  <span>this is the children</span>
</SimpleCard>
```

To use the children in your component you have to refer to it as the `children` prop:

```
export const SimpleCard = React.memo(function SimpleCard({
  title,
  description,
  children,
}) {
  const styles = useStyles();
  const shadowStyles = useOverShadowStyles();
  return (
    <Card className={cx(styles.root, shadowStyles.root)}>
      <CardContent>
        <Typography variant="h5" align="center" style={{ fontWeight: "bold" }}>
          {title}
        </Typography>
        <Typography variant="subtitle1" align="center">
          {description}
        </Typography>
        {children}
      </CardContent>
    </Card>
  );
});

export default SimpleCard;
```

Then the `children` prop will be basically replaced with `<span>this is the children</span>` or whatever toy want.

Another way is to pass your custom content as a custom prop like in the following example:

```
<SimpleCard customContent={<span>this is the children</span>} />
```

And then, as usual:

```
export const SimpleCard = React.memo(function SimpleCard({
  title,
  description,
  customContent,
}) {
  const styles = useStyles();
  const shadowStyles = useOverShadowStyles();
  return (
    <Card className={cx(styles.root, shadowStyles.root)}>
      <CardContent>
        <Typography variant="h5" align="center" style={{ fontWeight: "bold" }}>
          {title}
        </Typography>
        <Typography variant="subtitle1" align="center">
          {description}
        </Typography>
        {customContent}
      </CardContent>
    </Card>
  );
});

export default SimpleCard;
```

Comment: I prefer the first method but it didn't work. The second method works fine. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can maybe try something like this

```
<SimpleCard
          title={"Just shoot us an inquiry about your dream app or website!"}
          description={`Send us more details and we can discuss further`}
          displayButton={true}
/>
```

```
return (
    <Card className={cx(styles.root, shadowStyles.root)}>
      <CardContent>
        <Typography variant="h5" align="center" style={{ fontWeight: "bold" }}>
          {title}
        </Typography>
        <Typography variant="subtitle1" align="center">
          {description}
        </Typography>
      </CardContent>
    </Card>
    {props.displayButton && <Button />}
  );
```